# Least-norm solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am trying to find the least-norm solution of the following set of equations

$$\begin{aligned}
  y+z    &= -3\\
  x+2y+z &= -2\\
-2x-3y-z &=1\end{aligned}$$

Using the expression for the least-norm solution

$$x=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}b$$

I do the following

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\ 1&2&1\\ -2&-3&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A^T=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&-2\\ 1&2&-2\\ 1&1&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$b=\begin{pmatrix}-3\\ -2\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now my issue comes when calculating $(AA^T)^{-1}$, the reason begin is when I take the inverse I get a determinant of zero which means that the least-norm solution is $$x=\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$ which I am not entirely sure is correct. I have even checked my calculations on an online calculator and still get zero determinant. Is this correct?

Comment: There are 3 possible things that can happen either there is 1 solution no solution or inifinite solutions you know there is no distinct solution because the matrix is not invertible so check the other 2. (If there are no solutions or inifite number of solutions your method does not work)

Comment: I used 'Rouch ́e-Capelli Theorem' to determine that is has infinite solutions, so I should have a solution, unless I am getting mixed up here.

Comment: The 2,2 entry of $A$ should be $3$, not $2$.

Comment: Sorry 2,2 is actually a 3 I just miss typed when inputing in the matrix

Comment: Beacuse the question in the text book states finding using the method of least norm.

Comment: The (2,3) entry of $A^T$ is wrong; is that also a typo?

Comment: If the original system is consistent, then you must solve the system $(AA^T)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$. The solution you want is then $A^T\mathbf{u}$, where $\mathbf{u}$ is a solution. The system does not need $(AA^T)$ to be invertible to have a solution, you just need there to be a solution. So solve that system.

Comment: Note that the rank of $AA^T$ is the same as the rank of $A$; so if $A$ is a square matrix, the only way that $AA^T$ is invertible is if $A$ was full rank, i.e., invertible itself. In which case, the minimal norm solution would just be **the** (unique) solution to the original system. Your formula is useful when you have an **under** determined system, say $k$ equations in $n$ unknowns, $k\lt n$, where $A$ has rank $k$ (the equations are independent). Because then $AA^T$ is $k\times k$ of rank $k$, hence invertible. Any other case, it won’t be invertible.

Comment: Alternatively, note that the third equation is $-2$ times the second plus the first, so the system is equivalent to the $2\times 3$ system consisting of the first two equations. Work with *that*, which will give you an invertible $2\times 2$ matrix when you calculate $AA^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is consistent, then there exists $\mathbf{x}_0$ such that $(AA^T)\mathbf{x}_0 = \mathbf{b}$. Then the minimal solution to $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$ is $A^T\mathbf{x}_0$.

Of course, if $AA^T$ is invertible, you can find $\mathbf{x}_0$ by calculating $(AA^T)^{-1}\mathbf{b}$; but if it is not invertible, then what you need is to find **any** solution to the system, and then multiply by $A^T$ to get the answer.

Here you have 
$$AA^T = \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
2 & 3 & -4\\
3 & 6 & -9\\
-4 & -9 & 14
\end{array}\right).$$
So use Gaussian elimination to solve
$$\left(\begin{array}{rrr|r}
2 & 3 & -4&-3\\
3 & 6 & -9&-2\\
-4 & -9 & 14&1
\end{array}\right)$$
then take *any* solution to that system, multiply it by $A^T$ on the left, and you get the minimal solution to the original system.